# Link to an external file in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I want to provide links to files uploaded on the server in `iTextSharp` documents.

The problem I'm facing is the string containing my file path is getting mangled en-route from my code onto the page.

Let's say the full path for the file, I'm trying to link is `"C:\site uploads\some_file.txt"`.

I'm trying to create the link using the "Anchor" object, like so:

```
string path = "C:\site uploads\some_file.txt";
string name = "some_file.txt";

Anchor anchor = new Anchor(name, new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 12));
anchor.Reference = path;

pdfDoc.Add(anchor);
```

ASP.NET C# will double up those backslashes in "path", as it does, but `iTextSharp` will further alter the string to something like `C%5%20site%HCuploads%20some%34file.txt`, which does not work as a clickable link in my document. FYI, I know I didn't get my % codes just right; those are offered for example only.

I'm not trying to launch any external applications from my document, I just want to enable the user to download this file. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not using your path variable anywhere.

Comment: "p" was "path"; thanks for catching that typo. now corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you link to a local file? If someone else downloads that PDF on their machine, it won't have that directory.

The backslashes and colon are escaped.

Use https:// links. If you do want to link to local files, use a file:// link.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! They won't have the file on their machine, but they will be connected to the network; the file in question will be on a shared drive.

Can you please give an example of how I would use a "file://" link when building my anchor? Would it be like "file://C://site uploads//some_file.txt";?

Comment: For anyone who finds this later: I did change my file path reference to "file://" + [file path], and it works now. Marked as answered.